# need the url of an html file in js

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html file parent.html, which i access by http://foo.com/webtest/parent.html 

obviously on server this file is saved at public_html/webtest/parent.html 
now this html file has javascript, which creates an iframe on that html.
the src of the iframe is of an html file on the same server saved at  
public_html/bar/static/js/in/actions/inter.html

I want to give an absolute url to this file, as the src in that iframe, something like
src = http://foo.com/bar/static/js/in/actions/inter.html
but the thing is that this is not working, and i get a page not found inside the src.
any ideas as to what might be going wrong and wht i could do?

Comment: use `/bar/static/js/in/actions/inter.html` as your url

Comment: is the file accessible for the public? (permission on the file inter.html file itself) Have you tried it with a different file or a file on a different location?

Comment: yes... i wont create any permission issue if you already added that into public_html.

Comment: the problem is, even if i try opening the src 
http://foo.com/bar/static/js/in/actions/inter.html
in the browser, it gives a page not found.
the file is saved at public_html/bar/static/js/in/actions/inter.html
and the permissions are all ok.

Comment: have you verified that you can view the URL in a separate browser instance/tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have a problem with the webroot, i.e. public_html/webtest is set as a root of your site and thus anything outside this folder is not accessible for the app.

Can you verify this?